# Dart StreamController with two arguments

Tags: dart, flutter

I am currently developing on Flutter, using the BLoC pattern, and I would like to accept another parameter (or argument) in my `StreamController`. I could have used a Map or a class but is there a way to do it using Dart types?

Is something similar to `StreamController<int, String>` possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can instead make a `Stream` of a more complex object.

You could declare the following class:

```
class Foo {
  String val1;
  int val2;
}
```

And then create a `Stream<Foo>`

Comment: Okay. That’s what I thought. I just wanted to know if there are other ways. Thanks for helping me!!! (: